upload a face with ISAPI
I'm trying to upload a face using the POST method using this endpoint:
http://\<ip\>/ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json

And using this body:
{
"faceUR": "http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg",`
"faceLibType": "blackFD",
"FDID": 1,
"FPID": "A216627674",
"featurePointType": "face"
}

But the PostMan console always returns me the same error:
{
  "statusCode": 6,
  "statusString": "Invalid Content",
  "subStatusCode": "MessageParametersLack",
  "errorCode": 1610612761,
  "errorMsg": "FDID"
}

and I don´t know which value ISAPI expects to recieve on FDID. Maybe a specific value or data type?
I purchased a new facial hkvision recognition device.
The current system works with a couple of devices from a couple of years ago and apparently the structure to communicate between them is diferent. The current system uses the following method in PHP to upload an image using ISAPI, but unlike previous models of facial recognition devices, the new one does not accept the value of 1 in the FDID field.
// Upload Face 
public function setUserImageUrl($device, $employeeNo, $imageUrl)
{
    $host = $device;

    $url  = 'ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json';
    $body = '{
                "faceURL": "' . $imageUrl . '",
                "faceLibType": "blackFD",
                "FDID": 1,
                "FPID": "' . $employeeNo . '",
                "featurePointType":"face"
            }';
    $response = $this->request('POST', $host, $url, $body);

    if (!$response) {
        log::info('img fail');
        return false;
    }

    return json_decode($response);
}


Don't manually create JSON. Use json_encode instead with array value

This doesn't have much to do with ISAPI - that's just an interface to allow certain types of code to be run in IIS. What we need to know about is the specific module you're using, and its specification, and what parameters it expects etc. Do you have some documentation?

As above, don't build JSON by hand like this. It's fiddly and error-prone. Build a PHP object/array and then json_encode() it, for fully reliable results.

FDID is a string type.
"FDID" : "1"


There are many reasons why you faced such issues. For example, the FDID typically refers to the Face Database ID. It's possible that the value 1 is not valid because it does not correspond to an existing face library in your new device.
Try this code, I improved it a little bit
public function setUserImageUrl($device, $employeeNo, $imageUrl, $FDID)
{
    $host = $device;

    $url  = 'ISAPI/Intelligent/FDLib/FaceDataRecord?format=json';
    $body = '{
                "faceURL": "' . $imageUrl . '",
                "faceLibType": "blackFD",
                "FDID": ' . $FDID . ',
                "FPID": "' . $employeeNo . '",
                "featurePointType":"face"
            }';
    $response = $this->request('POST', $host, $url, $body);

    if (!$response) {
        log::info('img fail');
        return false;
    }

    return json_decode($response);
}


Don't build JSON by hand like this. It's fiddly and error-prone. Build a PHP object/array and then json_encode() it, for fully reliable results.
